# Adobe Animate CC into Vue.js component

Tags: vue.js, adobe, vue-component, animate-cc

does anyone know the best way to embed published Adobe Animate CC HTML5 canvas / JS files into a Vue.js component?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can include it in an iframe within the component, but that would require that you have the html/js files locally:

```
<template>
  <iframe src="myproject.html" scrolling="no" style="width:640px; height:480px; margin:0; padding:0; border:none; overflow:hidden"></iframe>
</template>
```

You should change the properties of the iframe tag to suit your needs.